# Does the use of null pointers mean that some memory is always unused?

Tags: pointers, memory-management

In C/C++ we're used to checking for null pointers before dereferencing them, e.g.

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
if (p != 0)
{
    /* Do something with the pointer */
}
```

Hence the memory manager can never return a pointer to the first memory address (where `p == 0`) as the calling program will assume that the memory could not be allocated.

Does that mean that the first byte or word (for alignment purposes) is always unused, both in the entire system memory space and the process' memory space? Or is this memory used by the system or kernel, which knows which null pointers it can dereference safely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, to make it clear, `malloc` returning 0 means signaling an error.

In most modern operating systems the *virtual address space* (addresses used in a program) is not the same as the *physical address space* (the real addresses that the memory understands). Most modern operating systems use paging. So the addresses used in a program (the address returned by `malloc` for example) aren't the same as the physical ones. The OS has some mechanism to make a correspondence between them.

The OS must simply never map anything at the physical address 0 **for a regular process** and that address will always be invalid if the process tries to access it. The OS itself, for its own benefit can access the memory at address 0 if it so desires.

Comment: The memory addresses that are returned are not page-relative then? That is, the first location within a page is not addressed by the offset 0

Comment: @Gnat I don't understand your question.

Comment: If I have a page 32 words long, the first word in that has the index 0 relative to the start of the page, then 1, 2.. 31. Addressing relative to the page itself is obviously not how addresses are allocated, but some OS-specified address that we really don't know how or why it gets there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sort of. Technically you could store something at address zero, but Windows doesn't allow - you get access violation and Linux doesn't allow - you get segmentation fault. This is done assist in having a designated special value that would mean "a null pointer - a pointer that clearly isn't pointing to any live object". Maybe there're systems where storing data at address zero is outright allowed, but still they would need some special value for a "null pointer".

Comment: Yes, I realise that, but that means that memory at address 0 can never be allocated, doesn't it?

Comment: @Gnat, as far as I remember there is IDT there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table

Comment: @Gnat: At least not with heap allocation.

Answer (score 1):

In most systems, there is something already at physical address 0. Some older processors simply start execution there when they come out of reset. Others may expect a vector table there (addresses for reset and interrupts). Often a ROM will be mapped there to contain these special things the processor is expecting, so it doesn't make sense to ever get a pointer there.

With virtual memory, your app and all its allocations live in a virtual memory space which is mapped to physical memory. My guess would be that the program is mapped in at virtual address 0 and so you'd still never expect malloc to return 0. This is more of a guess on my part, as I'm not intimately familiar with the details of virtual memory layout.

BTW, I've often thought processors should return zero when reading from a NULL pointer without page faulting. This would allow speculative prefetch of data even when there isn't any.

Comment: That makes sense, related to @Andrey's link above for x86. So yes, address 0 is used but not by anything most people worry about.